# How to pass Attribute to View without having Model as parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm overriding a method that belongs to super class. Method takes no parameter. Therefore, I'm unable to pass Objects to the View using Model. Anyone has any suggestion?

```
@Override
protected String connectView(){
    // I'd like to include an object in Model here
    // e.g. model.addAttribute(....) 
    // but unpossible because super does not take a Model as param
    return "connect/status";
}
```

Comment: could you please be more specific to the code ? You are returning a string but want to add attribute to model ?? Should be fair and square, but you've gotta give more here !!

Comment: Sure, When the Method is called, controller retrieves the "status.jsp" page and displays it.  I'd like to pass an Object to the View, usually I'd do this by placing it in a Model but this Method does not take any parameters.  I'm looking for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should suit your needs, using a `HandlerInterceptor`, a custom annotation `@Model` and reflection.

*Model.java*

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Model {

}
```

*RequestInterceptor.java*

```java
@Service
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws ServletException {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = request.getClass();
            if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Controller.class)) {
                for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Model.class)) {
                        field.set(request, new ModelMap());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // log("Cannot access model field of controller " + clazz.getSimpleName());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = request.getClass();
            if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Controller.class)) {
                for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Model.class)) {
                        ModelMap model = (ModelMap) field.get(request);
                        if (model != null) {
                            modelAndView.addAllObjects(model);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // log("Cannot access model field of controller " + clazz.getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

*applicationContext.xml*

```xml
<!-- register the interceptor -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="your.package.to.the.RequestInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

*YourController.java*

```java
@Controller
public class YourController extends ConnectController {

    @Model
    private ModelMap model;

    @Override
    protected String connectView(){
        // model is here available
        model.addAttribute("attrName", "attrValue");
        return "connect/status";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having at least the request object, I do not believe you can simply do what you are asking.  However, there are a few options:

1. Use a servlet filter...add the required values to the session there
2. Use the Decorator Pattern, in which you would create a instance of your class (controller in this case) within another wrapper class.  In your wrapper you would do the additional processing, then call the wrapped inner object (your wrapped controller), then do any final processing.
3. HandlerInterceptor like @sp00m suggests (although I have never used it, so I have no input there)

I am sure there are probably some other options out there, but I can't think of any others.